# Change IIS Authentication programmatically

Tags: iis, advanced-installer

Advanced Installer IIS application setup page has a subpage where I can select IIS Authentication mode before building the setup. I have selected Windows Authentication for now, which is then "hardcoded" into the setup file somehow.

But under certain circumstances only known at install time, a different authentication mode (Anonymous or Basic) should be set up.

How could I do so, during installation, programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this method](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19778)?

The only way for now it seems to be by duplicating the website, but changing the authentication method, and setting an installation condition on both websites.

Comment: I have tried to duplicate the application, but AI does not allow two applications with the same name. The app should be installed in the Default Web Site, but I cannot duplicate the Default Web Site.

Comment: use a public property for the name of the second one, that should bypass the unique name check

Comment: I now have done that. I have configured the property `IISPROPERTY` to hold the value `myapplication`, but the IIS configures an application with the name `Property.IISPROPERTY`...

Comment: I found the issue to be an unused dialog in the dialogs tab. If I added the dialog to the list of used dialogs or removed it from the installer altogether, it would work. Weird issue.